# can we use list view and scroll view in one activity...?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

can we use scroll view in list view I am getting confusion in that, when we are using list view then only we get scroll view. that's why i'm getting confusion.

Comment: Yes you can. Have you research on that?

Comment: I hope you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: advise use NestScrollView +Recycleview

Comment: if you want to know the difference look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820679/difference-between-scrollview-and-listview

Comment: thanks to all and thanks stack over flow